# sending/receiving broadcast messages over VPN connections

Tags: c#, vpn, broadcast

I'm in the process of building an application that will work on a bit large network so I'll have multiple subnets .. The network will be working over VPNs, so I'm thinking of having it to work as hub-and-spoke (I know this is a bad design, but I have some ideas to overcome the negative side)

Now, the most important thing ... I need to have the application to send broadcast message to every subnet in certain events (App close, App crash, ...) this is to allow remote Apps to use an alternate plan that I will be implementing as well.

Note: I'm in the network/application design phase, so I don't have any code ready yet. It would be great if you provide a working code sample (exe file would be great to test as well).

Comment: why the down votes?!! you can provide solution instead of down voting!!!!

Comment: I think you should be asking this at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: it a programming issue ... C#!!

Comment: I'm talking about it from the programming side ... So I just need to communicate with other PCs/servers on other subnets.

Comment: ¿What is the programming issue? I am re-reading and it seems like you question title should be something like: how to have an the application to send a broadcast message to every subnet in certain events?

Comment: So are you asking how to use UDP broadcasting in general? Getting that to work across multiple subnets is indeed more of a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is "how to have an the application to send a broadcast message to every subnet in certain events", here you can read an example on UDP broadcasting with C#: http://blog.eviac.com/2010/12/network-broadcasting-with-c.html